Shadow contour and parametric plot with mathematica
I am trying to find black hole shadow contour with respect to temperature. with metricf[r_] := -((2*M*r^2)/(g^3 + r^3)) + (8/3)*Pi*P*r^2 + 1. So here is my code,
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M*r^2)/(r^3 + g^3) + (8/3)*Pi*P*r^2; 
M = ((g^3 + r^3)*(8*Pi*P*r^2 + 3))/(6*r^2); 
T = (-(2*g^3) + 8*Pi*P*r^5 + r^3)/(4*Pi*r*(g^3 + r^3)); 
\[Xi] = ((3 + 8*Pi*r^2)^3*(g^3 + r^3)^3)/(216*r^6) + Sqrt[g^6 - 
(g^3*(3 + 8*Pi*r^2)^3*(g^3 + r^3)^3)/(108*r^6)] - g^3; 
rp = g^3/(2*r^2) + r/2 + (4/3)*(g^3 + r^3)*P*Pi + ((3 + 
8*Pi*r^2)^2*(g^3 + r^3)^2)/(36*r^4*\[Xi]^(1/3)) + \[Xi]^(1/3); 
rs = rp/Sqrt[f[rp]]; 
shadowcontour[met_, g_, p_, T1_, T2_] := Module[{T, r, \[Theta], 
shadowrad, photonrad, xi, rh}, 
rh = r /. Last[NSolve[T - (-2*g^3 + r^3 + 8*p*Pi*r^5)/(4*Pi*r*(g^3 + r^3)) == 0, r]]; 
xi = ((3 + 8*Pi*r^2)^3*(g^3 + r^3)^3)/(216*r^6) + Sqrt[g^6 - (g^3*(3 + 8*Pi*r^2)^3*(g^3 + r^3)^3)/(108*r^6)] - g^3; 
photonrad = g^3/(2*r^2) + r/2 + (4/3)*(g^3 + r^3)*p*Pi + ((3 + 8*Pi*r^2)^2*(g^3 + r^3)^2)/(36*r^4*xi^(1/3)) + xi^(1/3); 
shadowrad = photonrad/Sqrt[met[photonrad]] /. r -> rh; 
plot = Region[ParametricRegion[{shadowrad*Cos[\[Theta]], 
shadowrad*Sin[\[Theta]]}, {{\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, {T, T1, T2}}]]; 
plot]
shadowcontour[f, 0.3, 0.002418/0.09, 0, 0.21]

now perfomrfing shadowcontour[f, 0.3, 0.002418/0.09, 0, 0.21] gives no answer. Can anyone help me with it.

You have 2 boxes with the code. If I copy and paste in my notebook, there are some undefined variables. Then I see that you have definition of f somewhere, and parameters g and P are defined yet in another place. I think you will get better answers if you prepare a single copy-paste-able code.

actually I am trying to recreate fig 5 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.06120.pdf . They have used equation 16-21 and 24,25 to plot the figure with f(r0)=1 and the choice of P and g as mentioned. can you help me with it?

You should prepare a copy-paste-able code. Currently it consists of many pieces, extra work is needed to even start working on your problem.

Please look at This. There I have shared two of my notebook. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3163006

Actually I am not going to look and voting your post down because it does not match the standards here. It should be a minimal self-contain example, not something that people have to figure out on their own. It is strange to request enthusiastic people on Internet to follow additional links and papers just to answer your question.

I am really sorry.... I am new here and never asked anything before. So I am unaware of the standard here. I apologize for any rudeness and and try to fix it.

Kindly check the edited version. I have made the code in single box. Once again I apologize for rudeness and I will be careful from next time.  Thank you.

It is not the full answer, rather a suggestion how to organise the code. The problem with the existing code is in the mixing of notations. For instance, in the definition of f a parameter P is used, which is undefined. Later, a parameter p is used. In order to avoid this confusion, you have to explicitly specify all arguments. I recommend to define several functions:
 Clear[f,M,T,ξ,rp,rs]
f[r_,M_,g_,P_]:=1-(2*M[r,g,P]*r^2)/(r^3+g^3)+(8/3)*Pi*P*r^2;
M[r_,g_,P_]:=((g^3+r^3)*(8*Pi*P*r^2+3))/(6*r^2);
T[r_,g_,P_]:=(-(2*g^3)+8*Pi*P*r^5+r^3)/(4*Pi*r*(g^3+r^3));
ξ[r_,g_]:=((3+8*Pi*r^2)^3*(g^3+r^3)^3)/(216*r^6)+Sqrt[g^6-(g^3*(3+8*Pi*r^2)^3*(g^3+r^3)^3)/(108*r^6)]-g^3;
rp[r_,g_,P_]:=g^3/(2*r^2)+r/2+(4/3)*(g^3+r^3)*P*Pi+((3+8*Pi*r^2)^2*(g^3+r^3)^2)/(36*r^4*ξ^(1/3))+ξ^(1/3);
rs[r_,M_,g_,P_]:=rp[r,g,P]/Sqrt[f[rp[r,g,P],M,g,P]]

